# Showing that, for a convex polygon, $\text{area}\leq\frac{\text{perimeter}^2}{4\pi}$

Tags: geometry

> Let $A$ and $P$ be the area and perimeter of a convex polygon. Prove that $$A\le \frac{P^2}{4\pi}$$ and show that $4\pi$ is optimal.

I can show that $$A\le \frac{P^2}{\pi}$$ using the following argument: draw rectangles of height $\frac AP$ on the sides of the convex polygon. The union of their areas must be strictly less than $A$, since they intersect. Thus there is a point in the polygon that is not in the rectangles, and we can construct a circle centered at that point with radius $\frac AP$. Thus $$\pi\left(\frac AP \right)^2\le A\implies A\le\frac{P^2}{\pi}.$$ However, I am not sure how to prove the stronger result. Any help? Thanks!

Comment: I couldn't understand your argument, but it is still off by a factor of 4.

Comment: @Chrystomath the point is that my argument does not complete the proof.

Comment: I do not think that there is a shortcut in the proof, that the circle has the largest area, which first part is the proof that among all isoperimetric $n$-gons the regular one has the largest area.

Comment: @user i agree, but there might be a different approach than the one I outlined for the weaker result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:

1. Show geometrically that among all $n$-sided polygons of given perimeter $P_n$ the regular one has the largest area $A_n$.
2. From $\lambda_n=\frac{P_n^2}{4A_n}=n\tan\frac\pi n$ conclude $\lambda_n>\pi$.